# How to detect if user tried to click on save/save as option or pressed ctrl-S in Microsoft word using VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to detect when user press ctrl-S or click on Save option of Microsoft word using VBA excel macro code.

I found related links about [Save changes while closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196343.aspx) and [Detecting if a document is getting close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196343.aspx) but I not able to find some example code for detecting saving of word document.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately (or fortunately) Word does not work like excel and there the keybinding follows different logic. Thus, in Word, you should try something like this, to bind <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd>. The idea is that on openning of the file you tell the application to bind <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> to the `SaveMe` Sub.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()

    With Application
        .CustomizationContext = ThisDocument
        .KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyS), KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, Command:="SaveMe"
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub SaveMe()

    MsgBox "User Saved"

End Sub
```

Put the code in `ThisDocument`:

[image]

Until now, it works this way only for Ctrl+S. If you go for the Save through the menu, it will not follow this logic. This is what you should do then:

**For the general solution, follow these instructions:**

**I.** Create a `clsWord` and put the following code inside:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Call SaveMe

End Sub
```

**II.** Change the code in `ThisDocument` to this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myWord As New clsWord

Private Sub Document_Open()

    With Application
        .CustomizationContext = ThisDocument
        .KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyS), _
            KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, Command:="SaveMe"
    End With

    Set myWord.appWord = Word.Application

End Sub
```

**III.** In a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveMe()

    MsgBox "User Saved"

End Sub
```

Parts of the ideas are taken from the MSDN here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299.aspx But the code there was not complete :)

Comment: Its working only when pressing ctrl-S . Its not working while clicking on save from menu option.

Comment: It took me really a long time to do the edit, there is something wrong with the formatting of the code in SO when you select a numbered list, the format does not follow.

Comment: Its saying error  SaveMe is not defined in class module clsWord while clicking save in save menu

Comment: After that error I stop the running macros by clicking square blue color stop macro button. Now after clicking save in menu its doing nothing also not displaying error

Comment: @ascii_walker - yup, that's true. I simply edited the code a bit before posting and I did not try it. Now, the `SaveMe` is in a module and should work :)

Comment: Okay thank you for the prompt help. Is same possible for ctrl+ Shift+S or clicking saveAs from menu?

Comment: Its still not doing any thing(with no error) while saving from menu using code in link you mentioned

Comment: @ascii_walker - disregard the link, just follow the instructions from the **I**, **II** and **III** parts of my code. It works.

Comment: Yes, because the macro is activated with `Document_Open`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Viyata . I knew nothing about vba coding. Just trying some random code/bog since morning with basic knowledge of vba. Thank you for the  exact solution.